# Get users that are only subscribed in Laravel Cashier - all users not a user

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

Here is the query I tried to write and gives an error

```
$users =User::has('subscriptions', function (Builder $q) {
 $q->whereNotNull('ends_at');
})->get();
```

Getting this error

```
SQLSTATE[42601]: Syntax error: 7 ERROR: SELECT * with no tables specified is not valid LINE 1: ...sers"."id" = "subscriptions"."user_id") = (select * where "e... ^ (SQL: select * from "users" where (select count(*) from "subscriptions" where "users"."id" = "subscriptions"."user_id") = (select * where "ends_at" > now) and "users"."deleted_at" is null)
```

When I write this code I get results but need to filter result to get a list of subscribed users without calling `User::all()` then loop to filter.

```
User::has('subscriptions')->get();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use

```
$users = User::with(['subscriptions' => static function ($query) {
    $query->whereNotNull('ends_at');
}])->get();
```

Read [Constraining Eager Loads](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads)

> To query, you need to load the `subscriptions` relationship first.

Comment: Apologies, my comment got a little mangled due to a copy/paste error. This answer is _mostly_ correct, but check out this function in Laravel 9 too: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads-with-relationship-existence. `->with()` and `->whereHas()` are commonly used at the same time to filter and constrain, so Laravel added `->withWhereHas()` in Laravel 9 to handle that.

Comment: @TimLewis just now know there is a method `withWhereHas` in laravel 9. Thank you for the update.

Comment: No problem! You have no idea how many times I've done something like `$function = function(...)`, then `Model::with(['whatever' => $function])->whereHas('whatever', $function)->get()`; glad they finally added something to make that cleaner; cheers!

Answer (score 1):

**Solution is here**

```
$users =  User::whereHas('subscriptions', function (Builder $q) {
        return $q->active();
    })->get()->toArray();
```

Have a good day

Comment: gives an error App\Http\Controllers\DashboardController::App\Http\Controllers\{closure}(): Argument #1 ($q) must be of type Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder, Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder given, called in /var/www/creditfixrr.code/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php on line 1199

Comment: @NevilSaulBlemuss That just means you're using the wrong `Builder` import. Either fix it via `use Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder;` at the top of your file, or change `Builder $q` to just `$q` (remove Type Hinting)

Comment: I figured it out thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Do it like this

`$users = User::with(['subscriptions' => static function ($query) { $query->whereNotNull('ends_at'); }])->get();`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

```
$users = User::with(['subscriptions' => function ($query) {
    return $query->whereNotNull('ends_at');
}])->get();
```

Or,

```
$users = User::with('subscriptions')->whereHas('subscriptions', function ($query) {
    return $query->whereNotNull('ends_at');
})->get();
```

This will give you only subscribed users. But if you fetch all the users and then apply filter to the fetched result, then every row will be fetched from the database, which is not a good practice.